# $z_1, z_2,z_3$ are complex numbers, isn't $|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}+z_3||\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}-z_3|=|(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2})^2-z_3^2|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

$z_1, z_2,z_3$ are complex numbers, isn't $$|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}+z_3||\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}-z_3|=|(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2})^2-z_3^2|$$?

I ask because in my notebook it says that this is actually:$|(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2})^2+z_3^2|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The notebook has a typo, it seems.